# Should I install steam/origin on SSD and map some games to HDD or other way around?

Tags: steam, origin

Well the topic explains it all. I just reinstalled my PC. Now that I have a larger SSD I want to have some games on my SSD and some other games on my HDD.

I wonder if I should install Steam and Origin on the SSD, and move some of the games to my HDD, or can I also install Steam/Origin on the HDD, and move some of the games to the SSD? Is there a performance penalty?

Comment: The problem is the life expectancy of the SSD.

Answer (score 3):

Steam/Origin programs themselves are small, but may make many changes to there own directories, because of this I won't install them on the SSD.

Personally I'd map specific directories only; i.e

/dir/steam/steamapps/common/game1/ maps to SSD:/game1/

This way you get full performance from the SSD without having to mess with Steam/Orgin's settings.

Also I'd ONLY map games that have large loads, small games aren't going to give a large enough difference in load speed.

NOTE: The only time I'd install Steam/Orgin on the SSD would be if there were only say 1 or 2 games installed and I wanted performance from both, then instead of hassling with mapping directories I'd just install all on the same drive.

Comment: But is there a speedpenalty making link from HDD to SSD? Than directly on SSD?

Comment: Nothing that would be noticed. If the drive that the link is on isn't spun up then yes, but if it's already running no. This would only apply to the FIRST time accessing the game, once the game is running it's constantly running off the SSD, it won't even hit your main drive.